# Abusing ElGamal in order to attack a known encrypted text

Tags: cryptography, encryption

I saw a very interesting question regarding Elgamal cryptosystem that I don't know its answer. It is really interesting and I would be very happy if you could elaborate on it and explain the tricky part.

It goes like this: given Elgamal Cryptosystem:

1) Show how it is possible to create a valid new encryption from two different encryptions that we don't know their decryption

2)How can an adversary take advantage of this property in order to attack a known encrypted text?

I don't understand it, and it seems really cryptic and interesting. Tried digging on it but couldn't find the connection or insights.

Seems really fascinating, would appreciate if you could explain it so I can understand this riddle.

Comment: `1)` tells what we don't know about the two cyphertexts. What *do* we know?

Comment: This sounds a bit vague.  Can you provide a full reference to the original source where you encountered this?  What kind of attack are you looking for?  El Gamal is provably IND-CPA secure (under reasonable assumptions, assuming it is implemented correctly), so it won't be vulnerable to that type of attack; perhaps you're wondering about the existence of chosen-ciphertext attacks on El Gamal, using its homomorphic properties?  I hope you can [edit] the question to clarify.